# How to Set The first three digits for mobile number varification in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've a function ,

```
function validateDigit(event) {
        var key = window.event ? event.keyCode : event.which;
        if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 190) {
            return true;
        }
        else if ( key < 48 || key > 57 ) {
            return false;
        }else if(event.shiftKey == true){
            return false;
        }

        else return true;
    };
```

which takes only numeric numbers and no alphabets .But Now I Want To Set The First 3 digits of a mobile phone number as like 017/016/015/018 and after then there will be more 8 digits.how to do this ?

Comment: I Dont Want To Let The User Type Anything If He Didnt Put Those First 3 Digits ....Only If the user enters the first 3 digits correctly and then he can enter the next 8 digits ...

Answer (score 0):

Don't.

```html
<form action="javascript:alert('Submitted!');">
  <input type="tel" pattern="01[5-8]\d{8}" title="Mobile number beginning with 015/016/017/018" />
</form>
```

Done.

Comment: Now here comes the regex master

Comment: @AbhinavS.Chauhan More importantly, HTML5 validation allows the user to type what they want, then let them know if it's wrong. Blocking input is a very bad idea. The simplest example is, if I typo, I'll hit Backspace. But if it was blocked, then I've just erased my previous, correct input, now causing an error and more hassle.

Comment: People are full of ideas of how to annoy users. Just let users get to the result however they want, it only matters that the input is correct when the data is submitted.